# Dotnetnuke 7 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dotnetnuke

I'm starting to develop Dotnetnuke and I downloaded the package `"DotNetNuke_Community_07.00.05_Source"`. This package contains two solutions: `"DotNetNuke_Community_Source.sln"` and `"DotNetNuke_Community_UnitTests_Source.sln"`.

Apparently, **these solution files can only be opened using Visual Studio 2012**. I have installed the operating system Windows XP and Visual Studio 2010.

Is there any way you could open those solutions with Visual Studio 2010?.

Answer (score 0):

To develop for DotNetNuke you don't need to open the DNN solution, you should start by looking at Module Development templates.

My latest templates are all for VS2012, but you can use an older version here

https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/releases/view/93348

Basically, to develop for DNN, you create custom extensions (modules/skins) and install them. You rarely need to open up the DNN solution itself.

Comment: Ok, so, you install DNN on your development server and then you use a "Module Development template" to develop modules/skins, isn't it?

Comment: That's how most people go about things yes