# DotNetNuke and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I follow this question [DotNetNuke 7 with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829180/dotnetnuke-7-with-visual-studio-2010)

But may be this question needs higher understanding. My scenario is I want to use dotnetnuke CMS with visual studio 2013/2015. But I don't know how and from where I start. I want to make a website using CMS and manage Admin Panel.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Visual Studio at all to build a website using DNN.

You'll need to install DNN7.  Here is a good place to start:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBatw8mgPrg

Then, you can build out the website using the DNN CMS.

You may find that you want to install additional modules or a theme for your website.  Ask more questions or use Google when you get to that point.